# Handsontable - hide specific row ( by cell value)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, handsontable

How to hide specific rows in Handsontable.

I have buttons in DOM, each of them should hide specific rows.
For example: click button with class `alarm' should shide all rows which second column has value 'alarm'.

For now i do ugly thing. Every button click i loop overy my tableData and delete datas with 'alarm' then just load data and render table. But i can't do that becouse i have some dynamic datas so after render their disapear.

```
eveGrid.loadData(tableData);
eveGrid.render();
```

Comment: Could you share some of the HTML after the table has been generated? I might know a solution, but can't make it work for your code if I don't know how it looks like.

Comment: Could you maybe share a jsfiddle also? It doesn't really matter what the HTML looks like after render because Handsontable will override it immediately if you try to modify it (it's stateless, kind of like a React.js component).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically hiding rows is quite a complex task which is not documented in the Handosntable documentation. However, there is plenty of functionality available to implement it ourselves. As a matter of fact, I had to do this just last week so I can share with you a potential approach. It's really quite simple and similar to your solution, which is not ugly by the way!

What you want to do is keep two copies of your data. The first we can call `data`, and the second `activeData`. Initially, they both equal each other. Now this part is tricky and not easy to grasp but what you have to make sure is that these two arrays are DIFFERENT OBJECTS, but have the SAME REFERENCED ELEMENTS. What this means is that the arrays themselves are not `clones`, so an equality test would fail. However, their elements are clones. Your `activeData` elements are just references to the elements on `data`.

Once we have this set up, it's simple to implement the hiding of rows. Your click should look through `data` and set a new `activeData` based on the matching rows you want to display. Then just update handsontable with something like:

```
hotInstance.updateSettings({data: activeData});
```

And that's it! Note that that updating method will automatically trigger a `render()`.

Let me know how it goes, I'm curious to see if other people can use this approach.

Comment: I'll give a try this :) But i have some ajax data ( geolocation ) so its gonna be a little hard.

Comment: Ok. I tested it and it's working. I cached oryginal data in global variable. So  after every try of hide rows i iterate over oryginalData and push to newData all rows that i want to display. But still AJAX datas are the problem :/

Comment: What do you mean by ajax data being a problem?

Comment: For example if i have 100 rows and for each one i put in one cell ajax data. It's geolocation. I can request only few at on time. So the rows other are waitting for data. For put data i use  `table.setDataAtRowProp(rowId, 'loc',s);` if reuquest is succes/end.  So when i change table with new data it's looks like i'm losing reference to old rows but ajax is still requesting so old row ID =/= new row ID.

Comment: that may still work if you do the referencing like I said, and not just copy the values. but I'm not entirely sure. you can try posting code and maybe we can help

Comment: I think it wont becouse ajax is running on TABLE not on DATA. I will need to change ajax function to working with originalData, becouse now i take table and put data into rows. Anyway thanks for help :)